# What to do with the 'follow' activity when user unfollows a feed on GetStream?

Tags: getstream-io

I am trying to solve 'unfollowing feeds' with django-stream from getstream. Once someone unfollows another user, I delete my local FollowUser-model instance in the django database and send a feedmanager.unfollow_user(). I can see on the stream-dashboard that the Follow is deleted, the 'follow' activity is still listed.

**I cannot enrich this 'follow' activity anymore cause my UserFollow instance has been deleted. How are unfollows supposed to be handled?**

- Am I suppose to delete that 'follow' activity on getstream and what would the foreign_id be for that? It seems like no foreign_id is set in the feedmanager when following the user.
- Am I supposed to not delete the model instance and just mark it as 'archived' or something similar?
- Or is there a better way to handle it?

If I don't do anything, I get an activity from stream which can't be enriched cause my model instance has been deleted - and I don't seem to be able to find any information on how this is supposed to be solved in any of the docs...

Any help and pointers are highly appreciated!

Comment: There is also a github issue for others: https://github.com/GetStream/stream-django/issues/96

Comment: Haha, instead of answering this easy question - which should be documented somewhere anyhow -, you took the time to post a link to the GitHub issue where nobody is helping. Thanks, anyhow.

Comment: I am sorry, it slided. I will investigate it and will follow up on github. When we find the cause, we can copy here for others.